# Eigenvalues of p(A) where A is symmetric

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, symmetric-matrices

Let $A\in M_n(\mathbb{R})$ be a symmetric matrix and $p$ be a polynomial. It's clear that $\{p(\lambda) : \lambda \text{ is an eigenvalue of } A\}$ is a subset of eigen-values of $p(A)$ (by Spectral mapping theorem).
Is the set of all eigen-values of $p(A)$ is equal to $\{p(\lambda) : \lambda \text{ is an eigenvalue of } A\}$ when $A$ is symmetric?

Comment: if $A= U^{-1}DU$ then $P(A) = P(U^{-1}DU) = U^{-1} P(D) U$. Or alternatively: take an eigenvector $v$ of $A$ with eigenvalue $\lambda$ and note that $v$ is an eigenvector of $P(A)$ with eigenvalue $P(\lambda)$, since there is a basis of eigenvectors, this determines $P(A)$.

Comment: @Yorch Thank you

Comment: No problem I gotchu